# how to remove a particular commonwords from a list?

Tags: arrays, string, list, split, tcl

i need to retrive values from a list which are file names
the list contain

```
{  in2dffer34_ads.txt  in2dffer21_ads.txt in2dffer45_ads.txt in2dffer67_ads.txt }
```

i tried by giving

```
foreach name $listsofnames {
    set fbase [file rootname [file tail $name]]
    puts $out "$fbase"
}
```

it gives `{  in2dffer34_ads in2dffer21_ads in2dffer45_ads in2dffer67_ads }`
but i need to get only the names
like

```
{  in2dffer34   in2dffer21  in2dffer45  in2dffer67  }
```

Comment: So in other words, is the question about how to remove the "_ads" from the file names?

Comment: Do you know beforehand that `_ads` is the suffix to remove?

Answer (score 0):

A few ways (in a `tclsh` REPL session):

```
% set names {  in2dffer34_ads.txt  in2dffer21_ads.txt in2dffer45_ads.txt in2dffer67_ads.txt }
  in2dffer34_ads.txt  in2dffer21_ads.txt in2dffer45_ads.txt in2dffer67_ads.txt 
% lmap name $names { regsub {_ads\.txt$} $name "" }
in2dffer34 in2dffer21 in2dffer45 in2dffer67
% regsub -all {_ads\.txt\M} $names ""
  in2dffer34  in2dffer21 in2dffer45 in2dffer67 
% lmap name $names { lindex [split $name _] 0 }
in2dffer34 in2dffer21 in2dffer45 in2dffer67
```